# Bullets not visible in the game view when I move left

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine

So I am very new to unity. and I used this tutorial to create a shooting mechanic for my prototype. moving right and shooting projectiles works fine but when I move left the projectiles are not visible in the game view . I noticed they are in the scene when I run the game. I believe this has nothing to do with my code. since when I press the button it shoots and destroys. it's just not visible when I am moving left. is this a visual issue??

I have screenshots here to provide a better example. of what I'm experiencing. and the links to the movement and projectile code as well for any references. if anyone knows an easy fix it would be much appreciated. If you need to see my code i will include a follow up.

Movement:[https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n4N9VEA2GFo&t=20s[enter](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n4N9VEA2GFo&t=20s%5Benter) image description here][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NoZg9.png)

Projectile:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8TqY6p-PRcs&t=264s

Answer (score 0):

@Nyssa Wootton Welcome to StackOverflow.Try the bullet spawning approach you no need to attach a bullet with the player. Just assign a bullet in inspector and it will spawn a bullet whenever the user clicks on the button. have a look at this code

```
public GameObject bulletPrefab;
public Transform spawnPos;
public float bulletSpeed = 100f;

void Update () {
   if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)){ // on fire btn press
      var bullet = Instantiate(bulletPrefab , spawnPos , Quaternion.identity);

      // make sure you're prefab have rigidbody on it
      bullet.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(transform.forward * bulletSpeed , ForceMode.Impulse); 

      Destory(bullet , 2); // destorys after 2 second
   }
}
```